# Allow HTML tags in Bank Tranfer Payment instructions

Tags: magento2, html, payment-banktransfer

Default Magento payment method "**Bank Tranfer**" does not allow using **HTML tags** in **Instructions** text.

How can I change that?

Comment: Can you please give graphical detail what you actually want in your question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understood you want to add some HTML tags to Bank transfer Payment method.

By default Magento `escapeHtml` when rendering Instruction for `COD` and `Bank transfer Payment`.

We need to Create a small module which will override `getInstructions` function.

let's create a module `Pawan_Instructions`.

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Pawan_Instructions',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pawan_Instructions" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider" type="Pawan\Instructions\Model\Rewrite\InstructionsConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/Model/Rewrite/InstructionsConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawan\Instructions\Model\Rewrite;
 
class InstructionsConfigProvider extends \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider

{
    public function getInstructions($code)
    {
        if($code == 'banktransfer'){//check payment method is banktransfer
            return nl2br($this->methods[$code]->getInstructions());// removed escapeHtml function!
        }else{
            return nl2br($this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->methods[$code]->getInstructions()));
        }
    }

}
```

**Final Result will be:**

**Admin**
[image]

**Front**
[image: Admin]

**Note:**
I have checked and allow html tag for only `banktransfer` code, if you want for both, you can skip If condition.

**Update I**

Above code will only work for Front-end because for admin there is separate `phtml` file is responsible for showing payment method instruction.

If You also want to remove `escapeHtml` for Admin, follow below instruction:

Create `di.xml` (for override template) at:

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Banktransfer">
        <plugin name="override_template" type="Pawan\Instructions\Plugin\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Bank" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `Bank.php` at :

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/Plugin/OfflinePayments/Block/Form/Bank.php

```
<?php
namespace Pawan\Instructions\Plugin\OfflinePayments\Block\Form;

class Bank
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Banktransfer $subject)
    {
        $subject->setTemplate('Pawan_Instructions::banktransfer.phtml');
    }
}
```

create `banktransfer.phtml` at:

> app/code/Pawan/Instructions/view/adminhtml/templates/banktransfer.phtml

```
<?php
$instructions = $block->getInstructions();
?>
<?php if ($instructions) : ?>
    <?php $methodCode = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode());?>
    <ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_<?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?>" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?>-instructions-content checkout-agreement-item-content">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $instructions ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is working fine for the frontend. I have displayed an image on the frontend but in the backend, only the image URL is showing.

Comment: @VinodKumar Same prblm at my end. Did u got any solution for this?

Comment: @Nafsss please see my Update I in answer

Comment: @VinodKumar please see my Update I in answer..

Comment: In magento sales email?